# Equivalent behavior to unix cut -c in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

When I'm using bash and I wanna cut a part of a text file that I know in which line it is I use something like this:

```
X=$(sed -n ''$j'p' FINAL.CRD | cut -c 23-37)
```

That's because I usually know where is the information that I need, in that case between the characters 23 and 37.

I'm trying to do the same with python, but I am not finding how to do this using `np.loadtxt`

My text file is like this:

```
IMPZ               3  WWA        3.06  4.51  7.32
MTSF               2  W W        1.52  1.72  0.18
PI01               2   AA        4.02  3.32 10.26
PI02               2  A A        4.58  2.29  0.40
```

I want to get 3.06, 1.52, 4.02, 4.58. But, sometimes the file shows 'WWA' or 'W W', so, I cannot use `usecols`. But I know in which part of the line this numbers will always be, that's why i want something that operates on character/byte offsets like `cut -c`.

Comment: Do you want a generic python solution (as the title implies) or a `numpy`-specific one (as the question implies)?

Comment: Err. Do you want to know how to use `cut -c` from Python, or *how to do the same thing as `cut -c` in Python*? It's certainly possible to use the actual `cut` command from Python, but it's much better to do the same thing in native code.

Comment: I know how to do with bash, and I want to do this using python.

Comment: BTW, in bash, `''$j'p'` is **exactly** the same as `${j}p` or `$j"p"`. It doesn't actually give you the effect of having the expansion of `$j` quoted (suppressing string-splitting and globbing); to do that, you'd want `"$j"p`, or `"${j}p"`.

Comment: @SethMMorton, I would prefer a numpy solution, but, if it is impossible to do, can be a generic python solution

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, this `''$j'p'` is only to identify the line to the command, the most important element is `cut -c`, that defines the part of the txt file that I want to cut and import to my programn

Comment: @Rodrigo what's the end result you want in your numpy array?

Comment: @JonClements I tried to answer you editing my question.

Comment: Are the columns constant from the end? ie - it's always 3 columns and the last 3 columns you want to use?

Comment: @RodrigoMendesdaRocha, I realize that's the intent, but again, it's got a bunch of syntax that's serving no purpose at all (the paired `''` at the front that literally does absolutely nothing), and other omissions from the syntax that mean you're getting shell behaviors that do you no benefit (if your line number were `50` and `IFS=0` were set, then the the code would run `sed -n 5 p FINAL.CRD`, for instance).

Comment: @Rodrigo for instance - does `np.loadtxt('FINAL.CRD', usecols=[-3, -2, -1])` do what you want?

Comment: @JonClements, it doesnt work. If I use `usecols=-2`, for instance, I receive as array:
1.41
8.72
1.63
2.30
12.95
1.98
7.26

Comment: @Rodrigo even if that was formatted it wouldn't work well in comments - running it on the sample data you provided seems to give the correct results. (using `[-3, -2, -1]` that is)

Comment: @Rodrigo if you're interested in the first one - why aren't you using -3 instead of -2?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am not sure that I understand very well what you said. When I use this in my bash script, it works well. The script always return everything right.

Comment: @JonClements, ai used `np.loadtxt('FINAL.CRD', usecols=[-3, -2, -1])` but when I use `-1` the program returns:
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 6 columns instead of 3)
    Line #3 (got 6 columns instead of 3)
    Line #4 (got 6 columns instead of 3)

because the numbers of columns of the first line is different than the others.

Comment: @JonClements
I'm sorry, I was writing something wrong here. Now, it is working, thanks to you and for CharlesDuffy

Comment: @RodrigoMendesdaRocha, the original syntax works with the data you have, but it doesn't work with all possible data, or under all possible circumstances; the point of being in the habit of using using more robust syntax is so you don't get bugs in the presence of surprising data. (The worst data-loss event I've ever been present for was caused by random garbage being dumped into a filename by a bug; when a shell script then tried to process that file without quoting the expansion, it ended up expanding a wildcard and deleting all other content in the same directory).

Comment: @RodrigoMendesdaRocha, ...consider if somehow instead of `$j` containing a number you got `j='-i . 0p * '` -- now your `sed` command is not just reading one file, but is deleting content from every file in your directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Credit goes to Jon Clements for this `np.loadtxt` solution**:

`np.loadtxt('FINAL.CRD', usecols=-3)` returns the third field from the end of each line (where, by default, whitespace is used as the delimiter):

```
In [193]: np.loadtxt('FINAL.CRD', usecols=-3)
Out[193]: array([ 3.06,  1.52,  4.02,  4.58])
```

Even though the file may contain a different number of fields on each line, as long as the values you are looking for can be characterized as "the third field from the end", then `np.loadtxt('FINAL.CRD', usecols=-3)` can do the job.

---

**Here is how to read files with fixed-width fields using NumPy**:

[`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) can read files with fixed-width fields by specifying a list of integer (widths) as the `delimeter` :

```
In [180]: np.genfromtxt('FINAL.CRD', dtype=None, delimiter=[22,37-22], usecols=[1])
Out[180]: 
array([b'WWA        3.06', b'W W        1.52', b' AA        4.02',
       b'A A        4.58'],
      dtype='|S15')
```

where

```
% cat FINAL.CRD
IMPZ               3  WWA        3.06  4.51  7.32
MTSF               2  W W        1.52  1.72  0.18
PI01               2   AA        4.02  3.32 10.26
PI02               2  A A        4.58  2.29  0.40
% sed -n ${j}p FINAL.CRD | cut -c 23-37
WWA        3.06
W W        1.52
 AA        4.02
A A        4.58
```

---

Whereas, with `cut -c` you specify the column indices, with `np.genfromtxt` you specify the width of the fields in the `delimiter` parameter. Thus, the first field (which we want to ignore) has width 22, and the second field (which we want) has width 37-22. To grab only the second field, specify `usecols=[1]`.

---

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the file format, but if you want `[ 3.06,  1.52,  4.02,  4.58]`,
then given the file you posted, the `np.genfromtxt` command would be:

```
In [181]: np.genfromtxt('FINAL.CRD', dtype=None, delimiter=[25,37-25], usecols=[1])
Out[181]: array([ 3.06,  1.52,  4.02,  4.58])
```

Comment: I've suggested `np.loadtxt('FINAL.CRD', usecols=-3)` which should work fine given the example data but waiting for comments to clear that up... feel free to add that if it turns out it works if you want.

Comment: @JonClements: Thanks -- I learned something new. I didn't realize `np.loadtxt` could be used on files whose lines contain a different number of fields.

Comment: It's whether a direct equivalent is required. It may well be that using `-c` was an implementation detail that was more convenient using `cut` than the actual requirement being "the 3rd last column" which is covered more easily using a negative index and doesn't require a direct translation of fixed width handling... *shrugs*

Comment: True, counting fields from the end is more elegant.

Comment: Looks like `np.loadtxt('FINAL.CRD', usecols=-3)` is what the OP was looking for. Maybe you should post the answer?

Comment: Feel free to add to this one - it'll be more useful in a single answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: @unutbu this way works to me too. I wrote a little different that what you has written: `np.genfromtxt('FINAL.CRD', delimiter=[33,5], usecols=[1])`.

Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: This 2 ways of do this are very necessary. While for this problem `usecols=-3` is more elegant, other times I will need to use the unutbu method.

Answer (score 3):

While the use of `usecols` or `delimiter` as given in the accepted answer is good, here's an approach that is a bit closer, I think, to the `sed/cut` code.

`np.loadtxt` accepts input from anything that gives it lines.  That includes a list of lines.  So we can load the file, `cut` the lines, and pass that to `loadtxt` (or `genfromtxt`):

```
In [217]: with open('stack46005401.txt') as f: lines = f.readlines()
In [218]: lines
Out[218]: 
['IMPZ               3  WWA        3.06  4.51  7.32\n',
 'MTSF               2  W W        1.52  1.72  0.18\n',
 'PI01               2   AA        4.02  3.32 10.26\n',
 'PI02               2  A A        4.58  2.29  0.40\n']
```

Then use standard Python list comprehension and string slicing to get the desired columns

```
In [219]: [line[23:] for line in lines]
Out[219]: 
['WA        3.06  4.51  7.32\n',
 ' W        1.52  1.72  0.18\n',
 'AA        4.02  3.32 10.26\n',
 ' A        4.58  2.29  0.40\n']
```

and load.  With refinements to the string slicing we wouldn't even need the `usecols`.

```
In [220]: np.loadtxt(_, usecols=[1])   # _ is the output in Out[219]
Out[220]: array([ 3.06,  1.52,  4.02,  4.58])
```

This read and filter is useful in a lot of cases where the text file needs modification before it can read as a proper `csv`.